# Tableau error message "expected end to match if at character 0

Tags: if-statement, tableau-api, ends-with

I am trying to clean some free form data in a SAGE database so that we can quickly group entries into our accounts by supplier and therefore improve our management reporting. I have written the following code:

```
if contains([Narrative], "PA") then "Press Association"
elseif contains([Narrative], "Runningball") or contains([Narrative], "IPTV") then "Runningball"
elseif contains([Narrative],"Betradar") or contains([Narrative], "Sportradar") or contains([Narrative], "SPORTRAD") then Sport Radar
elseif contains([Narrative], "Abelson" then "Abelson"
elseif contains([Narrative], "SIS") then "SIS" 
elseif contains ([Narrative], "TX") then "TX"
elseif contains([Narrative], "Two Up") then "Two Up"
elseif contains([Narrative], "Champion Data") then "Champion Data"
END
```

I am then getting the message "Expected End to Match If at Character 0" but cannot see what I have done wrong. Any help is much appreciated

Thanks

Craig

Comment: It looks like Sport Radar is missing quotes

Comment: And the the line `elseif contains([Narrative], "Abelson" then "Abelson"` is missing a closing bracket on the `contains` function.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. Turns out the answer is better self review!

Answer (score -1):

https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_logical.htm

Seems like you need to explicity mention **ELSE** before ending the if statement which you have not:

```
elseif contains([Narrative], "Two Up") then "Two Up"
else "Champion Data"
END
```

Comment: The else clause is optional. By default the expression will evaluate to null if none of the conditions are satisfied.